# Failed Live Ubuntu 18.04 LTS USB Drive with Persistent Storage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, liveusb

I've tried different methods to create a live persistent copy of Ubuntu 18.04 in my USB drive. However, none of the methods I've tried (Rufus, Live USB Creator, etc) keep the data saved after booting the drive. I am trying this on my Surface Pro 6, could it be something with the fact that I'm using it on a surface pro?

Here's the last method I tried: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ubuntu 19.10 or later. There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855) with all versions prior to that that prevent Ubuntu from properly using a persistent partition residing on the same drive.

Also you need to use Rufus 3.7 or later (if you use Rufus), as Rufus 3.6, which introduced the ability to create a persistent partition, does not add the `persistent` kernel option to the GRUB/ISOlinux config files, precisely because of the bug above.

In other words, if you want to create an Ubuntu media with persistence, you should use one the Ubuntu daily-live ISOs from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) along with Rufus 3.7 from [here](https://rufus.ie/downloads/) (currently in BETA version).

Comment: Note: 19.10 will not be released for another month.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the article [linked in your question](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), the current Rufus version (3.6) does not offer this feature.

[Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) says it does, but Live USBs I have created with it and with persistence set on, fail to provide persistence.

There's another Windows based app which claims it offers persistence for Ubuntu only, [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), but I have not tested that yet.

Therefore, on the web page you cited, follow the lengthy process within Ubuntu titled **How to Make a Persistent Ubuntu USB Drive on Ubuntu** which I know works, try experimenting with [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), or experiment with the [pre-production version of Rufus](https://rufus.ie/downloads/) as [Akeo](https://superuser.com/users/286681/akeo), the developer of Rufus,  kindly mentioned above.

Comment: Unfortunately the article linked is outdated. Rufus 3.6 did introduce the ability to create persistent partitions, but this wasn't finalized until 3.7 because of the bug I mentioned in my answer. Please bear in mind that software may evolve faster than the articles that report about it... You can sort persistence with Ubuntu 19.10 and Rufus 3.6 if you just add `persistent` to the kernel options (which is the part that 3.7 automates vs 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that to create a persistent storage for a live usb successfully you first need to partition your hard drive and install Ubuntu on that (I've found this makes Windows far harder - though not impossible - to access, though I may have made a mistake in boot order or with the partition as I have to constantly put in my recovery key to get to Windows). Once done boot Ubuntu on your Surface - which I also used - and follow the instructions in the articles below to add mkusb, once that is done plug in designated usb for live usb persistent storage and use mkusb software to set it up. I hope this helps.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

https://howtotechglitz.com/how-to-create-a-ubuntu-usb-live-drive-with-persistent-storage/